# Winsock bind address "INADDR_ANY" clarification

Tags: sockets, networking, winsock

When i use the INADDR_ANY to specify the IP address to bind to socket, which later listens on a port, like so:

```
sockaddr_in sockAddr;

sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
sockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
sockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY; // use default
```

Will this socket structure allow external, internal, and loopback IP addresses to connect to to me?

I don't want to limit IP addresses that can communicate with me by putting my computer external address(ie: 122.215.214.3) in place of INADDR_ANY because then internal IP's can't connect.

I'm wondering if INADDR_ANY will bind with all 3 of my computer's IP addresses(external,internal,loopback).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When binding a listening socket, `INADDR_ANY` allows inbound connections on any **local** IPv4 address that directly belongs to the machine that the listening socket is running on, which includes loopback addresses.  However, you cannot bind to an **external** IP address that is outside of the machine, such as the public IP of a network router.  The router would have to be configured to forward incoming connections from the public IP to a private LAN IP that is assigned to the listening machine that it can bind on.

Comment: Assuming my home router port forwards port 205 to the computer inside my NAT that's running the server on port 205, would INADDR_ANY now work for external, internal(LAN), and loopback IP addresses?

Comment: Yes, but the server will still not have any knowledge of the external IP, nor does it need to. External connections will first arrive on the router and then be forwarded to the server's internal IP, just as if the connections had come from another computer on the same LAN. Your server won't know the difference.  As long as it is bound to the internal IP that the router forwards to, external clients will be able to connect to your server.